# The phrasal go along

Tags: meaning

The following dialog was between a basketball coach and one of team players:

> We hear you, dog. But we can't see you. The glare from your big,
>   black-ass head  is hella shiny, man. Damn, do you buff it?
>
> Oh, you got jokes to ***go along*** with that ugly jump shot of yours, huh?

Source: http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/c/coach-carter-script-transcript.html

I was a little confused by the meaning of go along in that sentence. I'm used to using go along in the meaning of continuing doing something which is not suitable here.

Comment: See also: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/go-along-with

Answer (score 2):

There is a "to go along" that works as a phrasal verb.   It means something along the lines of "to acquiesce" or "to fail to object".   This is not the "go along" in use here.

There is also a "to go along" that is synonymous with "to go on".  This has the meaning of "to continue" or "to persevere" with which you are already familiar.   This is not the "go along" in use here, either.

I don't regard this construction as a phrasal verb.   If you do wish to regard it so, then the phrasal is "to go along with".   This is an alternate form of "to go with", meaning "to accompany".

The reason I don't regard this as a phrasal construction is that the ordinary, literal meaning of "to go" applies.   Both "to go with" and "to go along" mean "to accompany" when "to go" means (as it commonly does) "to travel".

Answer (score 1):

In this context, "to go along" means something like "to complement". When two things are said to go together, it means that the two things belong together, in a sense.

Comment: Just an added note for the learner: when reading this answer, be sure you don't confuse _complement_ with _compliment_. They do not mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning you're used to is one of the common meanings of "go along with". The other common meaning is the one in the sentence you've asked about.

All that's being said is that the player has both an ugly jump shot and jokes. "To go along with" is simply indicating that the two things are associated.

In this case, they are primarily associated because they are both had by one person. There's also an *implied* association, in that the jump shot is ugly and disliked by the speaker, which implies that the jokes are ugly and disliked as well.

## Definition

Most dictionaries don't do a great job defining idioms, and I had to look around a bit to find [this reference](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+along), which might help.

The closest meanings there are 5, 6, and 7:

> 5) To be in accord with something.
>   6) To combine with some set so that a balanced or harmonious result is achieved.
>   7) To be a secondary effect of something.

But, I actually find better references by looking up the key word: along [[1](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/along)] [[2](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/along)]

In your example sentence, 'along' is an adverb modifying 'go'. Merriam-Webster's definition 3b is useful:

> 3b :  in association — used with with: *work along with colleagues*

as is Wiktionary's definition 1:

> 1. In company; together.
>      *I am going to the store. Do you want to come along?*